# Is it normal for logistic regression, to have predictors which have good Wald's Chi Sq, but still bad performance?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-strategies, concordance

I have trying to build a logistic model with some 10 variables. All of those variables have Wald Chi sq value<500. All are highly significant p-value<0.0001.
Event rate is about 3%.

The concordance: 55.1%, Discon:28%, Tied: 17%.

Is this behaviour normal? What can I do, to decrease the ties and increase concordance?

Comment: What is the sample size?

Comment: Sample size is about 2m

Comment: with 2m observations everything will be significant, making statistical tests pretty much useless.

Answer (score 4):

This is very normal.  Think about ordinary least squares linear models on a large sample size where small effects can be detected but the overall $R^2$ is only 0.07.  An over-simplified but somewhat valid interpretation would be that you can't predict individual outcomes very well but you can describe *tendencies*.  For a binary logistic model, the $c$-index (concordance probability; AUROC) of 0.55 is indicating very mild discrimination ability, i.e., lots of overlap in predicted probabilities between observations with $Y=1$ and those with $Y=0$.

Assuming the number of candidate variables is 10, you may not need to *build* a model but rather just to *specify* one.  Be sure to not assume linearity.  You can often get more predictive ability using regression splines to relax linearity assumptions.  Then there's consideration of interactions ...

Be sure to look at the model's pseudo $R^2$ and especially at the model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic with degrees of freedom equal to the number of candidate variables.  If the LR $\chi^2$ statistic is not significant the whole exercise is on thin ice.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what is the distinction between specifying a model vs building one. I have looked at your book and am pretty certain I understand what you mean by specifying a model - but what does it mean to "build" one, in contrast?

Comment: There are two overall ways to build a model.  One is using unsupervised learning (data reduction) masked to Y.  This is often a great idea.  The other involves "cheating" by using Y to select features and to specify the transformations for the features.  This leads to suboptimal performance on new data, and extreme instability in the set of selected predictive features.  Specifying a model means you specify all the terms and transformations to be used in fitting a fixed pre-specified set of regression coefficients.